# Using $_SESSION and PDO to get ID from MySQL Error: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

So I'm making a blog from scratch and can't figure this out for the life of me. Basically, once the user is registered they can make a post from dashboard.php which uses post_action.php.

Here's post_action.php's code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

session_start();
require 'connection_post.php';
require 'connection.php';

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    $author = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM userdata WHERE user=:user");
    $author->bindParam(':user',$user);
    $author->execute();
    $authorResult = $author->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, body, author, blog_time) VALUES (:title, :body, :author, now())");
    $stmt->bindParam(':title',$title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':body',$body);
    $stmt->bindParam(':author',$user);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'hi';

?>
```

The issue is I get the error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/blog/post_action.php on line 23

I tried just entering the raw string into the database which worked, but using the user's username instead of the ID will limit the ability to change the user's name.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The error tells you the problem. You're trying to use an array like a string. `var_dump()` the variables you're using on line 23 and check the data types.

Comment: @DiddleDot It gives me: array(1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" } and I understand the error I guess, I just have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Iterate over the array, or access the index you need from it.

Comment: @chris85 Sorry, but how would one do that? Or what would I google to figure that out?

Comment: Sounds like your index for user should be $_SESSION['user']['id']. But I don't know which variable you did var_dump on, so, I could be wrong.

Comment: You could use `foreach` or `for`, the `foreach` will be easier. Are you using `$user` or `$authorResult`?

Comment: @Kenyon Did it on $authorResult

Comment: Your code is out of date. Use `$authorResult['id']`. In the future make sure your error message is for the code being displayed, guessing isnt the best way to code/answer.

Comment: @chris85 Wait so where does that fit into the code? My session only includes the user's username.

Comment: Well, in the code you pasted, the error is on line `$stmt->bindParam(':body',$body);`. Which sounds like your HTML for your body input is messed up. So, you should either paste the complete context so the line number is correct, or just var_dump things til you figure out which one is an array and not a string

Comment: Your code is `$stmt->bindParam(':author',$authorResult);` currently, right? Assuming so you need to give the index to that array, `['id']`.

Comment: @chris85 It is.

Comment: @Kenyon line 23 is $stmt->bindParam(':author',$authorResult);

Comment: It needs to be `$stmt->bindParam(':author',$authorResult['id']);` as per what @chris85 just said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP form returns Notice: Array to string conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479114/php-form-returns-notice-array-to-string-conversion)

Comment: @Kenyon Thank you so much!

Comment: @chris85 Thank you too!